# why if condition doesn't handle username field in php-mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

If i enter wrong password it shows 'Wrong username or Password' but if enter wrong username and correct password it shows nothing. Why ? what should i change in the code?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['pwd'];

$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die();

mysql_select_db("dbname") or die();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
       if($row['uname']==$name && $row['pword']==$password)
       {
       echo 'Successfully logged in <br />';
       break;
       }
       else
       {
       echo 'Wrong username or password';
       }
       }
   mysql_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: SQL injection just waiting to happen

Comment: Tell me that this is for your own internal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you enter the wrong username the query returns nothing.

Then you don't get into the while loop.

You could change the query :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname='".addslashes($name)."' and pword='".addslashes($password)."'");
```

Then use mysql_fetch_row() only once (remove your while loop).

**EDIT**

```
<?php
function hash_password($password){
    $myVerySecretSalt = "pREkeSw2"; //don't use this string, create your own random one!
    return md5($myVerySecretSalt.$password.$myVerySecretSalt);
}

$name = $_POST['username'];
$password = hash_password($_POST['pwd']);

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die();

mysqli_select_db("dbname") or die();

$mysql_result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname='".addslashes($name)."' and pword='".$password."'"); 
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($mysql_result);
mysqli_close($dbc);

if(!$result){
    echo "Wrong username or password.";
}else{
    var_dump($result);
    echo "Successfully logged in.";
}

?>
```

EDITED for usage of MySQLi as mysql is deprecated since PHP 5.5

EDITED as for plaintext passwords.

It's never a very good thing to store passwords in plaintext in the database as they can be stolen in case of sql injection.

A way to protect your users password is to hash them, below is a basic implementation :

First create a function to hash a password :

```
function hash_password($password){
    $myVerySecretSalt = "pREkeSw2"; //don't use this string, create your own random one!
    return md5($myVerySecretSalt.$password.$myVerySecretSalt);
}
```

Then replace your third line `$password = $_POST['pwd'];` with this one : `$password = hash_password($_POST['pwd']);`

Here you go! (Just remember to use that same function on the password when you create the user account)

Comment: ok. can i use if like, if($result==null) echo'username not found'. or any other good method ?

Comment: what does .addslashes means ?

Comment: addslashes escapes the user entries, it prevents from sql injection hack as long as you keep putting values between single quotes in your sql request.

Comment: use `mysqli` not mysql it is deprecated

Comment: No mention about using plain text passwords? Major issue. `mysql_*` is one thing, but using plain text passwords is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly:

```
       <?php
       $name = $_POST['username'];
       $password=$_POST['pwd'];

       $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die();
               mysql_select_db("dbname") or die();
               $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
               $row= mysql_fetch_array($result)


               if($row && $row['uname']==$name && $row['pword']==$password)
                    {
                            echo 'Successfully logged in <br />';
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            echo 'Wrong username or password';
                    }

              mysql_close($dbc);
            ?>
```

your previous code didn't show anything becasue `row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` were not finding any record, and so returning immediately false (and exied the while)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you enter a username that does not exist in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your while loop. Just say:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."' AND pword = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'"));
if ($result) {
// Successfully logged in
} else {
// Login failed
}
```

Keep in mind that the mysql_real_escape_string is very important when accepting user input to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are authenticating a user, record must be unique.

Thus, you shouldn't be looping through anything:

Get rid of the loop and change your conditions

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['uname']==$name && $result){
  if($row['pword']==$password){
    echo 'Successfully logged in <br />';
  }else{
    echo 'Wrong Password';
  }
}else{
    echo 'No record found';
}

mysql_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code for this one. I recommend use mysql_fecth_row instead mysql_fetch_array beacause you need just one row.

```
  <?php

  // get, validate and clean your input variables
  $name = isset($_POST['username']) ? addslashes($_POST['username']) : '';
  $password =isset($_POST['pwd']) ? addslashes($_POST['pwd']) : '';

  // make your data base connection
  $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die();
  mysql_select_db("test_mysql") or die();

  // building the sql query and getting the result (remember filter by username and password)
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE uname = '$name' AND pword =   '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

  // using mysql_fetch_row (remember that just one user must match in the data base if not  something is wrong in register ...)
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

 // remember 0 => id, 1 => uname, 2 => pword
 if (is_array($row)) {
     echo "Welcome {$row[1]}";
 } else {
    echo 'Wrong username or password';
 }

 // close your connection
 mysql_close($dbc);
```